# Distinguish between the column number of cursor after and before the first character in a line

Tags: vimscript

Take for example,

```
" This is a line
```

> How do I check if my cursor is after the first `"` character or before it, if I'm in insert mode?

The reason I need this is because I have a `insert-mode` keymapping that depends on the `:h virtcol()` position of the cursor. If I use `<C-O>`, the cursor goes to normal mode and in position *after* the character `"`, when if I use `<Esc>`, the cursor goes to normal mode and in position *before* the character `"`. I could use `<C-o>` to distinguish if the insert mode cursor was before or after the character `"`. But the problem remains if the line has only one character, i.e. `"`. And I have some other reasons I want to use `<Esc>`.

My if-else blocks has mainly two cases:

- If the insert-mode cursor is before any other character, insert a `<Tab>`
- Otherwise, insert spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the column number in `:h Insert-mode`, `:h i_CTRL-R_=` needs to be used.

For example, the following function returns a `<TAB>` if the cursor has no text before it and required number of spaces otherwise.

```
function! SpecialTab() abort
    if (col('.') == 1) || (matchstr(getline('.'), '\%'.(col('.') - 1).'c.') =~ '\t')
        return "\<Tab>"
    else
        return repeat("\<Space>", (&tabstop - (virtcol('.') % &tabstop)) + 1)
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <Tab> <C-R>=SpecialTab()<CR>
```

Comment: You could also use a map-expr `inoremap <expr> <tab> SpecialTab()`.

Comment: @Ralf, both are basically same thing, AFAIK. `<expr>` uses the result of the function in {rhs}. `:h i_CTRL-R=` uses the expression register, but does the same thing, i.e. evaluates the function to get an expression. Is that right?

Comment: You are right, it's just an alternative. I don't know whether one is "better" than the other.

Comment: I find expr more readable because i am used to it, and it means you dont have to worry about the semantics of <C-r> having different meanings in different modes (ie in normal mode you must use expr)